# Fallback content when using GTL data lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for a way to set up default or fallback content if a data lookup yields no records.

```
{{.datasource Todays_Birthdays type=list}}
 {{.data}}    
      {
           "target" : "name:Todays_Birthdays", "filter" : "Birthday == 1"
       }
 {{/data}}
 {{Preferred_Name_First_Name}} {{Preferred_Name_Last_Name}} <br />
 {{.default}}There are no Birthdays today.{{/default}}
{{/datasource}}
```

This doesn't work as it applies the default to every result and doesn't display when there are no results.  I also tried {{.else}} not expecting much, and got it displaying with every record as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the Inverted Section tag instead of {{.default}}.

I'm thinking... {{^Todays_Birthdays}}There are no Birthdays today{{/Todays_Birthdays}}

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this method didn't work either.